# How to setup the UT of one flow if depend on some previous state?

Tags: corda

Here is my [demo source code](https://github.com/CIeNET-Corda/deliverydemo), I have created a flow "OrderPlaceFlow$Request" for order placing.

I want to write a UT for this flow - a order transaction between PartyC and PartyB, and this flow needs some Token state from PartyA and PartyB as the input.

How can I mock or simulating that PartyB has a Token state from PartyA?

---

As @Joel's suggestion, I add the previous state - a token state in PartyB, but still cannot query this state by API - getVaultService().queryBy.

Here is my code fragments below, or get the full source code from [Github](https://github.com/CIeNET-Corda/deliverydemo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/cienet/deliverydemo/order/FlowTests.java)

```
    TokenState tokenState = new TokenState(
            nodeA.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0),
            nodeB.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0),
            99);
    TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(network.getDefaultNotaryIdentity());
    transactionBuilder.addOutputState(tokenState, TokenContract.ID, network.getDefaultNotaryIdentity());
    CommandData commandData = new TokenContract.Issue();
    transactionBuilder.addCommand(commandData, nodeA.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0).getOwningKey());

    nodeA.transaction(() -> {
        try {
            transactionBuilder.verify(nodeA.getServices());
        } catch (TransactionVerificationException e) {
            assertEquals(1, 1);
        } catch (TransactionResolutionException e) {
            assertEquals(2, 2);
        } catch (AttachmentResolutionException e) {
            assertEquals(3, 3);
        }
        return null;
    });

    SignedTransaction partSignedTransaction = nodeA.getServices().signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder);
    SignedTransaction signedTransaction = nodeB.getServices().addSignature(partSignedTransaction);

    nodeA.getServices().recordTransactions(signedTransaction);
    nodeB.getServices().recordTransactions(signedTransaction);

    //find a Token State for order
    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria criteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);
    Vault.Page<TokenState> results = nodeB.getServices().getVaultService().queryBy(TokenState.class, criteria);
    List<StateAndRef<TokenState>> tokenStates = results.getStates();
    assertEquals(tokenStates.size(), 0);
```

---

Thanks Joel. Yes, I made some stupid mistake, now, I have fixed them.
But, my UT are still failed, and got those error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [net.corda.node.services.vault.VaultSchemaV1$VaultStates#PersistentStateRef(txId=8F1461B9985457E9F5BC2AB72FD637621BB64649F58BE6D66114E48F24B6A555, index=0)]

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:169)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
```

I did some research, this error will be raised when saving the 98 TokenState.
But I do not why, because the 99 TokenState was saved twice in PartyA and PartyB, but PartyB cannot save the 98 TokenState.

Hope somebody could help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Input states for flow testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491519/how-to-get-input-states-for-flow-testing)

Comment: @Joel, Thanks for you relay, but I still cannot query the pervious state. You can find the source code of UT in the questions.

Comment: I cannot replicate this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in your code above. In the final line, you assert that:

```
assertEquals(tokenStates.size(), 0);
```

Whereas, since you are expecting a state in your node's vault, it should be:

```
assertEquals(tokenStates.size(), 1);
```